# Risks and mitigation when getting a used iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, security, jailbreak

When buying or receiving a used iPhone, what security precautions should I take?

I intend to immediately wipe the phone by using iTunes to install a fresh iOS, as a clean install.

➥ What else should I do to address security concerns?

➥ If this phone had been through a [jailbreaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking), is there a way for me to tell? Is there any risk to using a previous jailbroken iPhone after doing a wipe and install of an all-new iOS?

My Question here is similar to: [*Steps after buying a used iPhone*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135950/17907). But that Question focused on practical issues. My Question here has a **focus on security**.

The only to-do item I know is to check for the *Activation Lock* feature being enabled. [Apple describes how to do this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365). Any other to-do items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I intend to immediately wipe the phone by using iTunes to install a fresh iOS, as a clean install.

That should be the only major step required. Do a clean iOS install (or factory reset the device). Make sure to install the latest public version of iOS supported by your model of iPhone.

> ➥ What else should I do to address security concerns?

Installing the latest public iOS release should take care of the security concerns whatsoever. You can further ensure if no 3rd party/unauthorized part replacements have been made. The iOS should be able to detect if any crucial components such as Home button or battery has been replaced by unauthorized means.

> ➥ If this phone had been through a jailbreaking, is there a way for me to tell?

No if the device has been reset to remove the Jailbreak.

> Is there any risk to using a previous jailbroken iPhone after doing a wipe and install of an all-new iOS?

None if you reinstall iOS which effectively removes the jailbreak.